# How to get user id of users who register on my website through registration social plugin

Tags: php, facebook, json, registration

How can I get the user id of the facebook user who is registering on my website using the facebook registration plugin.

The Graph Api says that each facebook object has a unique ID.

I want to know a way by which I can get this ID.

The json Code of the registration Plugin is:

```
<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                            client_id=325340244194060&
                                 redirect_uri=http://www.pingcampus.com/facebook_registration_plugin/store_user_data.php&
                            fields=[
    {
        "name": "name"
    },
    {
        "name": "email"
    },
    {
        "name": "gender"
    },
    {
        "name": "birthday"
    },
     {
        "name": "captcha"
    }
    ]'
                            scrolling="auto"
                            frameborder="no"
                            style="border:none"
                            allowTransparency="true"
                            width="500"
                            height="800"

             >
                    </iframe>
```

The PHP Code that i use to get the details is :

```
   <?php ob_start();
    define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', '325340244194060');
    define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', '2ab5cb734f39d8417569cc7be7a0e89a');





    // No need to change function body
    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
            return null;
        }


        // check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }

    if ($_REQUEST) {
        $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],
                        FACEBOOK_SECRET);


        /*
          "<pre>";
        print_r($response);
          "</pre>"; // Uncomment this for printing the response Array
        */





        $name = htmlentities($response["registration"]["name"]);
        $email = htmlentities($response["registration"]["email"]);
        $gender = htmlentities($response["registration"]["gender"]);
        $dob = htmlentities($response["registration"]["birthday"]);
        $phone = htmlentities($response["registration"]["phone"]);

} else {
        echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ the user_id is on the signed_request data.

I don't know PHP, but based on your above code and the information from the registration documentation, it should look something like this:

```
.....
$name = htmlentities($response["registration"]["name"]);
.....
$id = $response["user_id"];
```

Comment: I Figured it out before but the answer is correct, may help someone else!

Answer (score -1):

There is no way of doing this, instead you need to save the user's data in your database as soon as the user is register or login with facebook through your app.